# How to access multiple .traineddata files in Tess4j?

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

I am using Tess4j with java and I need to access more than one .traineddata files at a time.
I have trained the tesseract to create my own .traineddata files and I have kept them along with default .traineddata file which comes with Tess4j package.
By default eng.traineddata file is accessed while performing OCR. How can I access multiple .traineddata files at a time with Tess4j?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27763855/edit) your question and explain your problem in more detail. One-line questions are often downvoted, because they give the impression that the OP did not do any research on the web before asking a question here. More context and/or some code is often helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify combinations, such as:

```
instance.setLanguage("eng+spa");
```

See [documentation](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/docs/docs-1.2/).